# How to connect to Exchange 2010 within a Exchange Management Shell 2007

Tags: exchange-2010

I want to run scripts to manage both Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2010 servers. This is what I tried,

- Start EMS 2007
- run the script for Exchange 2007 servers
- run this command in EMS2007

  . 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange
     Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
- run the script for Exchange 2010 servers

The problem was I could connect to Exchange 2010 but I couldn't retrieve a lot of Exchange 2010 information with this method.

e.g. get-mailboxdatabase returned nothing with this method but I could get the databases if I start my EMS2010 from the menu.

My credential to manage Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2010 are the same.

What have I missed? Any hint is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.